# Parsing PDF files generated by MS Reporting Services - NO OCR

Tags: parsing, pdf

I need to parse PDF reports generated by MS Reporting Services, and store parsed data to database. Don't ask why, it's requirement. :=)

These are not image PDFs that need to be OCRed, so is there a simpler way to parse these files? Is there any tool, free or commercial available for this purpose?

Files contain report header, and a table with some data. Focus is on parsing table and a few fields from header (customer id, name, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iText (Java) & iTextSharp (c#) can get you the raw text using PdfTextParser.  It'll even tell you where each word is and the current graphic state (color mostly).  The trunk releases are under the AGPL.  MPL versions of iTextSharp do not have the parser package.

It's VERY difficult to pull data out as "tables"... usually.  You have to divine their format/location based on the lines and text on the page.

There are rare cases of Marked Content that actually defines tables, rows, and so forth, but I have yet to encounter one (that I didn't create myself).

Do you have a sample we could look at so we can give you a more detailed answer?

Comment: thanks for the answer. is there any alternative for iTextSharp?

Comment: There have been quite a few more general C#/PDF questions here on SO.  Take a look around.

Comment: I've googled PDFBox in .NET (http://www.keylimetie.com/Blog/2005/11/23/PDFBoxinNET/). I'll try with it. I understand the "tables" problem, thanks for the Marked Content info. I wanted to know if there's a tool that can reliably parse a table from PDF, but all I'm getting is a single line of text :)

Comment: I seem to recall a few commercial apps out there that claim to be able to do it, but knowing the issues they're up against: I'm skeptical.  OTOH, the problem gets much easier if you know where the table will be in advance.  If these are all the same report[s], you can cheat quite a bit.

Comment: Exactly, I've realized that when I've parsed one of the reports with PDFBox. :) Thanks for the help!